# How to exclude files and directories from deploying using cloudbuild yaml?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, yaml

I deploying a cloud function in GCP using my cloudbuild yaml file. But, I want to exclude specific files and directories from deploying. How do I do it ?

Below is my yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: installing_npm
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: 'API/groups'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: deploy
  args: [
          'functions', 'deploy', 'groups', 
          '--region=us-central1',
          '--source=.', 
          '--trigger-http', 
          '--runtime=nodejs8', 
          '--entry-point=App', 
          '--allow-unauthenticated',
          '--service-account=xaxaxax@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
        ]
  dir: 'API/groups'
```

Attaching a screenshot below. In this screenshot, in the `groups` directory, I want to deploy only the directory `src` and the files `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and exclude the rest from the directory. As of now, the whole contents of groups directory are getting deployed which I don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `--ignore-file` to specify an ignore file, or create a `.gcloudignore` in the root directory of the execution context.

The `.gcloudignore` file uses the same syntax and behaves exactly as the well known `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Great answer. Just something to add: if you have a `.gcloudignore` and a `.gitignore` file, only the `.gcloudignore`. If you  have only `.gitignore` file, it's take into account.

Comment: Good point @guillaumeblaquiere. Thanks for improving the answer.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Is this documented somwhere? `If you have only .gitignore file, it's take into account.` It's not mentione [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore).